# change file names in a folder using terminal

Tags: shell, unix

In config folder of my application, i want all the `*.yml.sample` files to be converted into `*.yml`. Can someone please help? I want this to be done using terminal. Is there a single command to do this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, using `sed`:

```
ls -1 *.yml.sample | sed "s%\(.*\).yml.sample%mv & \1.yml%" | sh
```

or more simply:

```
ls -1 *.yml.sample | sed "s%\(.*\).sample%mv & \1%" | sh
```

**EDIT:**

`ls` is convenient, but parsing it can fail with spaces, newlines etc. In this case, a loop and a bash string substitution is best:

```
for i in *.yml.sample; do mv "$i" "${i%.sample}"; done
```

Some reading for you:

[Rename multiple files with Linux](http://www.go2linux.org/rename-bulk-files-with-linux-console-command)
[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

HTH

Comment: thanks for responding. But it works for the file names without space. But it is failing for the file name with space. Please Help!

Comment: Thanks steve. I feel its simply the best!

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple shell loop and the `basename` command to strip off the second extension.

```
for f in *.yml.sample; do
    mv $f `basename $f .sample`
done
```

Comment: thanks for responding larsmans. Just curious to know whether there is a single command using a pattern or something like that.

Comment: @Arun: Linux systems usually have a command called `rename`. That's not standardized, though; it comes with Perl.

Comment: When i hit this command in the terminal its waiting for an input from me. I m confused of what to provide. Can you please help.

Comment: @Arun: you probably made a typo. Works fine here.

Answer (score 2):

That's a simple one for `mmv` to do.

```
$ mmv "*.yaml.sample" "#1.yaml"
```

The quotes are important here.

Comment: can you please tell how is that?

Comment: `mmv` may not be portable on all systems, but an excellent alternative to `rename` +1

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -iname "*.png" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.png}@2x.png"' {} \;
```

I have used this to rename all files in current folder from ".png" to "@2x.png". This is too useful for giving name to retina images. Widely used for ios developers.